# Парсинг контента

Tags: php

Привет мир!

Пишу парсер, раньше проблем не возникало, а сейчас в ступоре, подсобите, кто может. Есть код страницы, нужно вытащить все, что между всеми `<td width="25%"`, а там будут ссылки, их надо, пробовал уже все, что можно... наверно, плохо знаю ману по библиотеке. :)

```
<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.тест.ру/');

    foreach($html->find('td[width=25%]') as $el) {
    // нужно с содержимого td[width=25%] вытащить ссылки
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может так поможет?

```
$el->find("a")
```

или

```
    foreach($html->find('td[width=25%]/a') as $el)
```

или

```
    foreach($html->find('td[width=25%] a') as $el)
```

если это не xpath